# how do i write a such a bash script that can search, rename, and replace files

Tags: bash, shell

I have a whole bunch of files in source folder need to be updated to destination folder. the layout in source folder is flat, no sub directory such as:

```
src\a.h
   \a.c
   \b.h
   \b.c
   \c.h
   \c.c
```

The destination folder contains multiple layers deep sub directory such as:

```
dst\App\a.h
   \App\a.c
   \USBD\CDC\b.h
   \USBD\CDC\b.c
   \USBH\CORE\FUNCTION\c.h
   \USBH\CORE\FUNCTION\c.h
```

I need to search all the files in the "dst" directory recursively, if any of them match any of the file in the "src" directory, then rename the one in "dst" as XX.sav (XX is the original name) and copy the one from "dst" to "src".

thanks

Comment: Is the final sentence correct, or do you want to copy the one from src to dst?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I need to back up the one in dst first then copy the one from src to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you actually want to copy from `src` to `dst`, that `src` and `dst` are siblings, and that the command is run from the common parent directory, try:

```
find dst -type f -exec sh -c 'test -f src/${0##*/} && 
    { mv $0 $0.sav && cp src/${0##*/} $0; }' {} \;
```

If the final two assumptions are not correct, try (untested):

```
find /path/to/dst -type f -exec sh -c 'test -f $1/${0##*/} && 
    { mv $0 $0.sav && cp $1/${0##*/} $0; }' {} /path/to/src \;
```

You should be careful: if there are any existing `.sav` files in `dst` they may be overwritten, and if there are any `.sav` files in `src` you may wind up with `.sav.sav` files in dst that are duplicates of the related `.sav` file that this command is itself creating.  Use `mv -i` to address these issues if they are relevant.  If the number of existing files is high, `mv -i` may not be an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps to finding a solution to your problem.

First of all, you need to iterate over all files in `src` folder to make sure that you know what to look for in `dst`. This can be done easily in bash like this:

```
for filename in src/*
do
    echo "$filename" # simple sanity check
done
```

Now that you know what you're looking for, you can use command `find` to try to find the files in `dst`. Since this command enables recursive look-ups itself, you don't need to do anything special. However, you'll probably want to look for a name of a file, not the whole path also containing directory structure. Something like this should work.

```
for filename in src/*
do
    pattern=$(basename $filename) # remove folder from filename
    for another_filename in $(find dst -name "$pattern")
    do
        echo "$filename -> $another_filename" # another sanity check
    done
done
```

Now that you have a file from `src` matched with a file from `dst`, you can simply use `cp` and `mv` to achieve what you need.

This is nowhere near the shortest possible solution, but it should be easy to understand and improve once you figure out the commands you need.